# Using the same scope for subsequent Javascripts in Ant

Tags: javascript, ant, rhino

Apache Ant allows for use of scripting as described [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html).

Here is a minimal **build.xml** that illustrates the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="test" basedir=".">
    <target name="test">
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            function echo(msg) {
                var echo = project.createTask("echo");
                echo.setMessage(msg);
                echo.perform();
            }
            testvar = "ok";
            echo("testvar=" + testvar);
        ]]></script>

        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            function echo(msg) {
                var echo = project.createTask("echo");
                echo.setMessage(msg);
                echo.perform();
            }
            echo("testvar=" + testvar);
        ]]></script>
    </target>
</project>
```

The `echo("testvar=" + testvar);` in the second script fails with a runtime exception because `testvar` is not defined in its scope, indicating that the scope is different for each invocation.

What I am trying to do is to avoid having to set up the same utility functions like the above `function echo(msg)` in every script, but without a shared scope this won't be possible.

Answer (score 3):

For reusing functionality use [macrodef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html), use any ant task(s) inside `<sequential>...</sequential>`.
For sharing values between isolated parts, use ant api and the project scope of your ant script and 
create / overwrite a property / userproperty.

```
<project>
 <macrodef name="foobar">
  <attribute name="foo"/>
  <attribute name="prop"/>
  <attribute name="val"/>
   <sequential>
    <script language="javascript">
     // no project.createTask("echo") needed just use
     println('@{foo}');
     // create property, property with same name will be overwritten
     // if it's a userproperty, means defined via ant -f build.xml -Dkey=value
     // create or overwrite it with project.setUserProperty(key, value);
     project.setProperty('@{prop}', '@{val}');
    </script>
   </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <foobar foo="yada,yada.." prop="someprop" val="somevalue"/>

 <echo>$${someprop} => ${someprop}</echo>

 <script language="javascript">
  //access some property from project scope
  println(project.getProperty('someprop'));
 </script>

 <!-- use macrodef from script task -->
 <script language="javascript">
  var macro = project.createTask("foobar");
  macro.setDynamicAttribute("foo", "blablabla..");
  macro.setDynamicAttribute("prop", "someprop");
  macro.setDynamicAttribute("val", "somevalue");
  // or macro.perform();
  macro.execute();
 </script>
</project>
```

output :

```
[script] yada,yada..           
[echo] ${someprop} => somevalue
[script] somevalue             
[script] blablabla..
```

-- **EDIT** after comment --
There's no other way to share values etc. .. in ant that i know of.
When reading your refined requirements in comment, i believe switching to
 [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) is the way to go. It's possible to incorporate existing ant scripts etc.

Comment: Great answer. It pretty much shows how to use the features of Ant to solve the problems I mentioned, though it's only possible to pass strings through the project properties, is that right? I've upvoted the answer as I've learned from it, but I'm a Javascript programmer and I'd really like to be able to use Javascript to manage scope, with all the goodness of closures, anonymous functions etc. If you're telling me it's not possible to share the JS scopes I'll accept this answer, otherwise I'll wait for a while to see if there are any other suggestions.